# Resetting and advancing counter using same line

Tags: comparator, counter

For a project, I need to use one analog signal to control a binary counter -- to both advance and reset, e.g. +1 V square pulse goes to clock and -1 V pulse resets the counter, or 1 V goes to clock and 2 V resets.

1. If I used the latter option and connect input signal to analog comparator (MAX912) and its outputs to CD74HC4024E counter, 1 V pulse brings high to clock, 2 V brings high to *both* clock and reset. The counter advances on negative transition. Would the falling edge of the reset (2V→0V) lead to advance immediately after the reset? [image: circuit with comparator]
2. If yes, can I use a counter with positive transition (CD74HC4520) instead?
3. The possible problem can be obviously solved by using +1 V and -1 V pulses. How should I treat the signal? I am thinking of inverting the input signal using and opamp/inverting amplifier and rectifying both inverted and non-inverted signals, the first one goes to clock, the other one goes to the reset input. Is there any easier solution? [image: circuit with opamps]
4. Can a comparator with zero negative supply voltage be used for comparing negative voltages? (Vdd=5, Vss=0, V+=-1, V- input signal)

If you come up with any other ideas, I'd be grateful.

(For my application, I need a fast counter, controlled using tens of nanoseconds pulses (so the counter running on 5+V), and an arbitrary signal up to 3 Vpp is available. Hence the proposed components.)

Comment: "I need a fast counter, controlled using tens of nanoseconds pulses" How far do those pulses have to travel? How do you handle signal integrity? Have you looked at those pulses?

Comment: What do you mean by '10s of ns'? the CD74HC4024 has a minimum input pulse width of 15-25ns depending on temperature and exactly what the voltage of the supply line is.

Comment: I can set the pulse width, but want to make it as fast as possible, so I guess 5 V and 50 ns should be safe.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? The slower you can make the edges, the easier the signal integrity will be.

Comment: I would like to be able to reset and count to 16 in under 3 us, so pulse+gap < 180 ns.

Comment: So why not 75ns pulses?

Comment: Sure, why not... What's your point?

Comment: I'd say @user1937198 's valid point is that precise specs are needed to get a quality answer. You've done a lot of the work in writing a decent question so far. But it's missing a pulse spec. Detecting 10ns is significantly different to detecting 50ns to detecting 75ns with the ICs you're looking. So: that's the point, and it's a good one.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the missing pulse width specification, with a tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any logic you desire between comparator outputs and the counter input. You can also interchange the comparator (+) and (-) inputs to invert the comparator output's logic level.

> Can a comparator with zero negative supply voltage be used for comparing negative voltages? (Vdd=5, Vss=0, V+=-1, V- input signal)

No, but it doesn't matter. Use a resistive network to scale and shift those voltages into the comparator's input voltage range.

Comment: So all I need are two resistors between the input signal and 5 V used as voltage divider and comparing voltage in the mid point?

Pulses come from an AWG, the designed circuit is part of the lab equipment.

Comment: MAX912 datasheet reads "Input Range Extends Below Negative Supply" and "Inputs Can Exceed Either Supply." Do I understand it wrong that single supply comparator can compare negative voltages?